# How do I correctly enable "AutoPlay" of animation

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, wordpress

I am using an html snipped to play audio when the website is loaded.  This seems to be working correctly.
Now, I need the animation of the "sine wave" to "auto play" when the audio "autoplays" upon page load.

The audio autoplays as expected, but the "animation" only plays on the "click" function of the wave itself.

I tried adding the below line below "audio.autoplay" (for the autoplay of the audio), but it does not seem to be the correct way to allow the wave animation to start when the page loads the autoplay of the audio:

```
audio.autoplay = true; // for autoplay audio
$(this).addClass('fa-play'); // for autoplay animation
```

```js
var audio = new Audio("https://api.twilio.com/cowbell.mp3");

audio.autoplay = true; // add this
$(this).addClass('fa-play');

$('#play-pause-button').on("click",function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('fa-play'))
   {
     $(this).removeClass('fa-play');
     $(this).addClass('fa-pause');
     audio.play();
   }
  else
   {
     $(this).removeClass('fa-pause');
     $(this).addClass('fa-play');
     audio.pause();
   }
});

audio.onended = function() {
     $("#wave").removeClass('fa-pause');
     $("#wave").addClass('fa-play');
};



const path = document.querySelector('#wave');
const animation = document.querySelector('#moveTheWave');
const m = 0.512286623256592433;

function buildWave(w, h) {

  const a = h / 4;
  const y = h / 2;

  const pathData = [
  'M', w * 0, y + a / 2,
  'c',
  a * m, 0,
  -(1 - a) * m, -a,
  a, -a,
  's',
  -(1 - a) * m, a,
  a, a,
  's',
  -(1 - a) * m, -a,
  a, -a,
  's',
  -(1 - a) * m, a,
  a, a,
  's',
  -(1 - a) * m, -a,
  a, -a,

  's',
  -(1 - a) * m, a,
  a, a,
  's',
  -(1 - a) * m, -a,
  a, -a,
  's',
  -(1 - a) * m, a,
  a, a,
  's',
  -(1 - a) * m, -a,
  a, -a,
  's',
  -(1 - a) * m, a,
  a, a,
  's',
  -(1 - a) * m, -a,
  a, -a,
  's',
  -(1 - a) * m, a,
  a, a,
  's',
  -(1 - a) * m, -a,
  a, -a,
  's',
  -(1 - a) * m, a,
  a, a,
  's',
  -(1 - a) * m, -a,
  a, -a].
  join(' ');

  path.setAttribute('d', pathData);
}

buildWave(90, 60);
```

```css
#play-pause-button{
  cursor: pointer;
  align-items: center;
  border: none;
  display: flex;
  height: 110px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 110px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px; 
  bottom: -4px;
  right: 10px;
}

svg {
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#wave {
  stroke-dasharray: 0 16 101 16;
  -webkit-animation: infinite;
          animation: moveTheWave 2400ms linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveTheWave {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: -133;
    transform: translate3d(-90px, 0, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes moveTheWave {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: -133;
    transform: translate3d(-90px, 0, 0);
  }
}

.fa-pause path {
animation-play-state: running !important;
}
.fa-play path {
animation-play-state: paused !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="play-pause-button" class="fa-play">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
     width="80px" height="60px"
     viewBox="5 0 80 60">
    <path id="wave" 
        fill="none" 
        stroke="#262626" 
        stroke-width="4"
        stroke-linecap="round">
    </path>
  </svg>
</div>
```

[Page where auto load error occurs](https://neue2.run-time.co.za/)

Comment: You should be aware that, it is bad practice to play audio/video before a user interaction

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes#webaudio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you got some typos in your script, as long as you put the play and pause functions reversed, in CSS and in JS..

try the snippet

```js
var audio = new Audio("https://api.twilio.com/cowbell.mp3");
$(document).ready(function() {
audio.autoplay = true; // add this
$('#play-pause-button').addClass('fa-play');
});
$('#play-pause-button').on("click",function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('fa-play'))
   {
     $(this).removeClass('fa-play');
     $(this).addClass('fa-pause');
     audio.pause();
   }
  else
   {
     $(this).removeClass('fa-pause');
     $(this).addClass('fa-play');
     audio.play();
   }
});

audio.onended = function() {
     $("#wave").removeClass('fa-pause');
     $("#wave").addClass('fa-play');
};



const path = document.querySelector('#wave');
const animation = document.querySelector('#moveTheWave');
const m = 0.512286623256592433;

function buildWave(w, h) {

  const a = h / 4;
  const y = h / 2;

  const pathData = [
  'M', w * 0, y + a / 2,
  'c',
  a * m, 0,
  -(1 - a) * m, -a,
  a, -a,
  's',
  -(1 - a) * m, a,
  a, a,
  's',
  -(1 - a) * m, -a,
  a, -a,
  's',
  -(1 - a) * m, a,
  a, a,
  's',
  -(1 - a) * m, -a,
  a, -a,

  's',
  -(1 - a) * m, a,
  a, a,
  's',
  -(1 - a) * m, -a,
  a, -a,
  's',
  -(1 - a) * m, a,
  a, a,
  's',
  -(1 - a) * m, -a,
  a, -a,
  's',
  -(1 - a) * m, a,
  a, a,
  's',
  -(1 - a) * m, -a,
  a, -a,
  's',
  -(1 - a) * m, a,
  a, a,
  's',
  -(1 - a) * m, -a,
  a, -a,
  's',
  -(1 - a) * m, a,
  a, a,
  's',
  -(1 - a) * m, -a,
  a, -a].
  join(' ');

  path.setAttribute('d', pathData);
}

buildWave(90, 60);
```

```css
#play-pause-button{
  cursor: pointer;
  align-items: center;
  border: none;
  display: flex;
  height: 110px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 110px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px; 
  bottom: -4px;
  right: 10px;
}

svg {
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#wave {
  stroke-dasharray: 0 16 101 16;
  -webkit-animation: infinite;
          animation: moveTheWave 2400ms linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveTheWave {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: -133;
    transform: translate3d(-90px, 0, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes moveTheWave {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: -133;
    transform: translate3d(-90px, 0, 0);
  }
}

.fa-pause path {
animation-play-state: paused !important;
}
.fa-play path {
animation-play-state: running !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="play-pause-button" class="fa-pause">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
     width="80px" height="60px"
     viewBox="5 0 80 60">
    <path id="wave" 
        fill="none" 
        stroke="#262626" 
        stroke-width="4"
        stroke-linecap="round">
    </path>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: @BurhamBSoliman - That has fixed the problem of autoplaying the animation, thank you. The audio autoplay however does not work if the page is refreshed, but only when it initially loads, is that something which I need to update in the snippet?

Comment: i set the audio play according to page ready you can take it out by removing 
`$(document).ready(function() {

});`

Comment: and please mark the answer as right to let ppl know that you got an answer

Comment: thank you. I have removed the above, but the audio still only plays on page load, and not reload. anything else I need to remove perhaps?   I will mark it now, yes, thank you

Comment: @ultramel1987 oh i miss understand what you need, okay, just put back the ready statement, then add this line `audio.loop = true;` after `audio.autoplay = true;` line

Comment: @BurhamBSoliman Thank you. I have added it, it still doesnt seem to autoplay on refresh though, perhaps I did somethign wrong?

Comment: use `audio.play();` instead of `audio.autoplay = true;`

Comment: @BurhamBSoliman.  it is doing the same. I tried to remove the jquery call in the html as I'm using Wordpress which loads the jquery automatically. it is now giving this error:  $(document).ready(function() { is not a function
and "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause()."

Comment: as per what @Chris said, you need to set it after user interaction as long as most of platforms wont allow it as it been considered as ads,

Comment: @BurhamBSoliman. thank you. can the auto play be triggered by a timeout delay - rather than an OnLoad or on Document Ready function? would that maybe solve it?\

Comment: @ultramel1987 actually no, there might be any action from user side, or the user might allow play permission like this [image](https://ibb.co/jw364Th)